# how to update inner array of objects in react use state

Tags: reactjs

```
 {moduleCode: ‘xxx, moduleName: ‘xxxx’, subModules: Array(4), features: Array(2)}
```

when I tried the below code is working

```
setNewSelectedModules(prev => [
    ...prev,
    { moduleCode: e.target.id, moduleName: e.target.value }
]);
```

I'm not able to update the inner array
But pls guide me on how to update subModules, which is an inner array of objects ->

```
suModules:[{moduleCode: ‘xxx, moduleName: ‘xxxx’}]
```

Comment: What is the previous state? What should the new state look like?

Comment: Please try this: `setNewSelectedModules(prev => ({...prev, subModules: [...prev.subModules, {moduleCode: 'someCode', moduleName: 'someName'}]}));`. The assumption is that the useState is like so: `const [newSelectedModules, setNewSelectedModules] = useState({});`. In other words, `newSelectedModules` is an object which has the prop `subModules`.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, its an empty state and I recreate the array of objects after the user selects modules, submodules, features etc... (the original array is having the entire modules, sub modules etc...)

Comment: I am getting TypeError: prev.subModules is not iterable,

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `map`. Update the "some-condition" as per your scenario.

```
setNewSelectedModules(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    subModules: prev.subModules.map((item) => {
        if("some-condition"){
            return {
                ...item,
                moduleCode: e.target.id,
                moduleName: e.target.value
            };
        } else {
            return item
        }
        
    })
}));
```

Comment: @Paul, let me know if this is not clear

Comment: thank you Amila, let me try and get back.

Comment: I am not able to use the above code since I am creating this array while user gives input for the module, sub module selections.

Comment: What does your initial state look like? can you add more relevant code into the question?

Comment: const [newSelectedModules, setNewSelectedModules] = useState('');